# php Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, fatal-error

I have this code:

```
function getBlockName($blockId){
    $block = classContent::findById(conn(), $blockId);
    echo $block->getBname();
}
```

now if the function outputs something works fine, if it doesn't output anything I have the

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBname() on a non-object in...
```

I'm pretty new to php so I couldn't find a solution on how to handle the error.

Any help would be very much appreciated! :)

Mauro

Comment: It means `classContent::findById` does not return an object. Maybe because you pass an non existing `$blockId`.

Comment: You did have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Call+to+a+member+function+on+a+non-object *before* asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it doesn't return an object if nothing was found.

```
function getBlockName($blockId){
    $block = classContent::findById(conn(), $blockId);
    if ($block !== false && is_object($block)) {
        echo $block->getBname();
    }
}
```

Edit: recommendation from comment.

Comment: Never use empty() for such things. Either check for false or use is_null/is_object.

Answer (score 1):

This means `$block` is not an object, probably it's `NULL` or `false` in some cases (nothing found).

Answer (score 0):

If your findById does not return anything, then $block is not an object. And you can not call members (`getBnam()`) from something that is not an object. Hence the error.

You might want to add somecode to catch the event of not-returning anything.

like:

```
function getBlockName($blockId){
    $block = classContent::findById(conn(), $blockId);
    if(!$block){
       echo 'error!;
    }else{
        echo $block->getBname();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing for the result of `$block`. In most cases you'd do:

```
<?php
function getBlockName($blockId){
    $block = classContent::findById(conn(), $blockId);
    if($block)echo $block->getBname();
}
?>
```

But I'm a little uncertain as to what findById returns. So here's something that's bound to work:

```
<?php
function getBlockName($blockId){
    $block = classContent::findById(conn(), $blockId);
    if(method_exists($block,'getBname'))echo $block->getBname();
}
?>
```